# Copying with memcpy externally?

Tags: android, c++

Is it possible to copy a function to an external application's shared library in memory? If so, how? I'm trying to achieve external hooking by making a trampoline hook externally.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211229-00/?p=106061

Comment: I'm trying to do this for android, not windows.

Comment: It doesn't matter. This issues are the same.

Comment: After the compiler takes advantage of the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), the function might not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This require very deep understanding of the binary formats used by the operating system. Not all code is relocatable, your code must be compiled with `-fPIC` for this to work for sure. You will need also to resolve manually all external symbols. In fact, you will have reimplement parts of the ELF loader. It is possible but definitely not trivial and very machine dependant.
Also you will have to find a way around the new execution restriction - nowadays most OSs have various protections against writing in executable memory regions.